# Cannot add reference to Skype4COM .dll on Windows 7 x64

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64, skype4com

I received the dialog indicating successful registration of Skype4COM.dl using regsvr32.
However, when I try to add a reference to Skype4COM 1.0 Type Library from the COM tab into my VS 2008 project, I get "A reference to Skype4COM 1.0 Type Libary' could not be loaded.

Did not run into this problem on 32 bit XP.

Dependency walker says I am missing GPSVC.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL but these are found in c:\system\windows32 and c:\program files\internet explorer respectively.

How do I fix this?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type library embedded in skype4com.dll is not very clean and generates warnings.  Enough to stop the IDE from adding it.  You will have to do it by hand.  Start the Visual Studio Command Prompt and run the [tlbimp.exe utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to generate the import library.  You'll see the warnings but get the .dll you need.  Afaik the warnings are benign as long as you only use it from a project which has the Platform target setting at "x86".

Comment: I am now getting "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {830690FC-BF2F-47A6-AC2D-330BCB402664} failed due to the following error: 80040154." when I attempt to instantiate a Skype object.  I have Skype 5.5.0.124 installed. Any ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I just found out that if I run the command prompt as administrator and use c:\windows\system32\regsvr32 to register dll, I can import it into VS using from COM tab of Add Reference dialog.

Comment: ... and I error in retrieving COM class is solved after building my solution targetted for x86 as you specified above.  Thanks again.

Comment: I have the same error, but I can't register dll even as administrator. I get "The module "C:\Windows\System32\mydll.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.". What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

My approach is different, but it works for me.  In command line: regsvr32 skype4com.dll , then you can add reference as usual in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions [here](http://donchevp.blogspot.com/2008/08/skype4com-lib-how-to-register-skype.html) finally allowed me to solve this problem and explained the problems I was having.  Wanted to post it in case anyone else might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your app for 32bits.
Build -> Platform Target: x86.
This works on 32bits and 64bits